# Is there a way for requestdispatcher forward method show url of landing page

Tags: java, forward, requestdispatcher

Is there a way for  `Requestdispatcher` forward method show URL of landing page

```
RequestDispatcher r = request.RequestDispatcher("error.jsp");
r.forward(request,response);
```

Does not show URL `error.jsp`

Comment: i need a immediate result

Answer (score 1):

No, It'n not. URL won't change with `forward`.

Use  `sendRedirect`  to see the url change in browser.

```
response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
```